# Need regex to match routes in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am having routes configuration like below,

```
$route['sf_network/list'] = "sf_resource/list";
$route['sf_client/list'] = "sf_resource/list";
$route['sf_subnet/list'] = "sf_resource/list";
$route['sf_ip_address/list'] = "sf_resource/list";
$route['sf_network/describe/(:any)'] = "sf_resource/describe";
$route['sf_client/describe/(:any)'] = "sf_resource/describe";
$route['sf_subnet/describe/(:any)'] = "sf_resource/describe";
$route['sf_ip_address/describe/(:any)'] = "sf_resource/describe";
```

Similar to this I am also need to configure routes for add and modify pages. so, its becoming too large lines of coding. Is there anyway to use regex for reduce the multiple lines of coding. I am new to PHP and this is my first project. Any suggestion would be most grateful. Thank you.

**Solution**

```
$route['sf_([A-Za-z_-]+)/list'] = "sf_resource/list";
$route['sf_([A-Za-z_-]+)/describe/(:any)'] = "sf_resource/describe/$2";
```

Comment: $route['sf_([A-Za-z_-]+)/list'] = "sf_resource/list";
$route['sf_([A-Za-z_-]+)/describe/(:any)'] = "sf_resource/describe;

Comment: Thank you @Deepak I have also got the same one.